# How to display a confirmation dialog before splash screen is closed in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms app using MVVMCross targeting Android & iOS, now I need to perform some validations on the server before the app is fully loaded, with the result of those validations I need tho present a confirmation dialog with a meesage to the user and preventing him to continue before he accepts or cancels the dialog.

Here is the mock code I need to have working:

```
public class App : MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        //... a lot of Dependencies registering

        RegisterCustomAppStart<AppStart>();
    }
}

public class AppStart : MvxAppStart
{
    private readonly IMvxLog _log;
    private readonly IMyApiService _apiService;

    public AppStart(IMvxApplication application, IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(application, avigationService)
    {
        _log = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxLog>();
        _apiService = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMyApiService>();
    }

    protected override Task NavigateToFirstViewModel(object hint = null)
    {
        //This is all the code I need to make work, all these lines are pseudo code

        //Do my server side validations
        var myObj = await _apiService.staticValidations();

        //Here I need to validate myObj, something like:
        var result = false;

        if(myObj.boolValue) 
        {
             var result = await showConfirmationDialog();

             //result should contains the value depending on user's selection: if pressed cancel or ok button
        }

        //At this point the splashscreen must continue freezed

        if(result)
        {
            var mvxBundle = new MvxBundle(new Dictionary<string, string> {{BaseViewModel.NavigationBarParameter, "false"}});

            await navigation.Navigate(myMainViewModel, mvxBundle);
        }
        else
        {
            //Other things
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to show the confirmation dialog using some nuget packages but I got errors because the libraries tries to attach a view to the navigation stack, and at this point the navigation stack has not been initialized yet.

I'll appreaciate your help on this

Comment: you could also use  [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to call native dialog in OnStart() method

Answer (score 1):

You can allow the App to be loaded and make a new Page called StartupPage which has the similar background as the SplashScreen. On that page you can show a ConfirmationPopup. If the validation is correct you can navigate the user to the first page or you can just close the App or close the confirmation page and the user will be on the Splashscreen background Startup Page.

I suppose that you will not be able to show a confirmation dialog on the SplashScreen or before your app has started.